# Laravel caching queries with eager loading

Tags: mysql, caching, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

the Laravel caching mechanism works fine when doing:

```
$users = User::remember(10)->get();
```

but when doing:

```
$users = User::with('posts','addresses')->remember(10)->get();
```

it doesn't cache the entire set of queries, specifically the join query (eager loading).

Is there a way to cache all the queries that are performed in the above example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it inline:

```
User::with(['posts' => function ($q) {
  $q->remember(10);
}, 'addresses' => function ($q) {
  $q->remember(10);
}])->remember(10)->get();
```

or in the relation definition:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Post')->remember(10);
}
```

Comment: Jarek, what if a related model is updated. Should we invalidate the entire eagerly loaded query or just the specific model change? I asked this on [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-properly-do-caching-in-laravel-52) as well.

Comment: @AliGajani Let's start with the fact, that `remember` method was removed some time ago, so using L5+ means you need to do it on your own. That being said, you end up with custom caching system where obviously you would invalidate/refresh appropriate cached queries in case of update. If you based your cache on the query itself (like `remember` method did), then you need to invalidate only the one against related table, that has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cache [eagler loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) queries in that way. You have 2 solutions to choose - [cache::remember](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/cache) engine:

```
$users = Cache::remember('custom_cache_key', 10, function() {
    return User::with('posts', 'addresses')->get();
});
```

or build single query using query builder:

```
...->select(...)->join(...)->where(...)->remember(...)
```

Comment: you should explain how the code answers the question.